# Get Parent list of a lookup column in Powershell

Tags: powershell, column, lookup-column

I need a script to retrieve the parent-list from a lookup-column. 
I've already made a script to list all the lists with a lookup column, but I want to know from where the lookup column gets his data.
This is what I've got already:
The output gives the url, the list-name and the lookup-columnname.

```
$TTNExcludeLists = "Solution Gallery", 
            "Workflow Tasks", 
            "Master Page Gallery"

Get-SPSite -Limit All | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | 
  Select -ExpandProperty Lists | 
  Where { -Not ($TTNExcludeLists -Contains $_.Title) } | 
  Select -ExpandProperty Fields | 
  Where { $_.TypeDisplayName -eq "Lookup" -and 
          $_.Hidden -eq $false -and 
          $_.FromBaseType -eq $false } | 
  Select {$_.ParentList.ParentWebUrl}, 
         {$_.ParentList}, 
         Title | Sort-Object Title | Format-table -AutoSize -wrap
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`SPFieldLookup.LookupList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms459069(v=office.15)) property to get related list GUID and then use `SPListCollection` indexer to get this list. Remember to cast this property to Guid before (it's string representation), to use correct indexer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but isn't that just for C# & VB? I can't seem to  find a good example in Powershell.

Comment: Definitely not. PowerShell is based on .NET, so generally if you can use some class in C#, you can use it in PowerShell too. When you use SharePoint snap-in and cmdlets like Get-SPSite, you just get standard SSOM object (SPSite in this case) and you can operate on it like in C# (but of course syntax can differ a little).